# Need Ignor required field in some case

Tags: html, coldfusion

Greeting,
I need to avoid validation for required field. When I click one button and this field will be required, and form will not submitted unless... And if I click another button, required field will be ignored, and the form submitted(Both are buttons within the same form for example).

```
 <cfform name="SubmitToHR" action="Action.cfm">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form" bgcolor="FFFBF0">#Var#</td>
        <td width="39">
            <cfinput type="Text" value="#Comments#" name="Comment" size="39" maxlength="100" lass="Text5" style="height:21" required="no">
        </td>
        <td width="127">
            <cfinput name="CheckDate" type="datefield" value="#Paycheck#" class="Text" style="height:21" size="18" required="yes" message="Select Date">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center"> 
            <cfinput name="Operation" type="submit" class="ButtonOrange" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center"> 
            <cfinput name="Operation" type="submit" class="ButtonRed" value="Not Approve">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You would do this with javascript.

Comment: Don't use ColdFusion's UI tags. They are outdated and incredibly inflexible. If you need help with understanding and converting them, have a look at [ColdFusion UI - The Right Way](https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<script>
    function checkInput(mode)
    {
        if (mode == 1) {
                if (SubmitToHR.CheckDate.value.length == 0)
                {
                    window.alert('Select Date');
                } else {
                    document.forms['SubmitToHR'].submit();
                }
        } else if (mode == 2) {
                document.forms['SubmitToHR'].submit();
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>

<cfset Var = "Test1">
<cfset Comments = "Test1">
<cfset Paycheck = "01/01/2020">
<form name="SubmitToHR" method="post" action="Action.cfm">
<cfoutput>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="Form" bgcolor="FFFBF0">#Var#</td>
        <td width="39">
            <input type="Text" value="#Comments#" name="Comment" size="39" maxlength="100" class="Text5" style="height:21" required="no">
        </td>
        <td width="127">
            <input name="CheckDate" type="Text" value="#Paycheck#" class="Text" style="height:21" size="18" required="no" message="Select Date">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center"> 
            <input name="Operation" type="button" class="ButtonOrange" value="Submit" onclick="checkInput(1);">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center"> 
            <input name="Operation" type="button" class="ButtonRed" value="Not Approve" onclick="checkInput(2);">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</cfoutput>
</form>
```

Comment: Also, just wondering if is it possible to change an HTML attribute's value using JS?

`if 1 AttibuteValue = 'yes' else AttibuteValue = 'no'`

Comment: What kind of attribute? Do you have a particular attribute in mind?

Comment: yeah, for example `required="yes"` and to change this `"yes"` to `"no"`

Comment: Sure:  
document.getElementById("CheckDate").required = true;  
In order to use this, you need to add id="CheckDate" to the line:  
<input name="CheckDate" id="CheckDate" type="Text" value="#Paycheck#" class="Text" style="height:21" size="18" required="no" message="Select Date">